# Should I add Capacitance on Switched High Side

Tags: power, capacitance, system

Following from [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/384526/isolating-power-in-communicating-5v-sub-systems/384530), which remains open... if I've got a microcontroller switching the high-side power to a sub-system, using a circuit like this:

[image]

... should I add bulk and/or decoupling capacitance on the SENSOR_5V net? I *do* have bulk and decoupling capacitance on the +5V net. In the broader context of this circuit, SENSOR_5V basically just goes to a connector pin, which supplies power to a separate board through a short cable.

So, now I'm wondering (in light of the referenced prior question) whether it would be a help or a hindrance to add say a 10uF ceramic and a 100nF ceramic to the SENSOR_5V net? Or maybe even a 100uF tantalum perhaps? What do you think?

Comment: How much current does the sensor draw? How much of that load is variable?

Comment: I'd put a 5V6 zener on the output to ground to catch fast back emfs from the cable inductance.

Comment: @ThePhoton I think it has a peak draw around 300mA at startup,  then 40mA average,  with bursts of 150mA activity periodically.

Comment: With those numbers I'd think 10's or 100's of uF is not a bad idea. If it were 1-2 mA I'd say 100 uF is probably overkill.

Comment: @Andyaka I think I know what you mean,  but consider posting an answer with a schematic representation for the benefit of the community? Also consider we're are talking about a 4 inch cable.

Comment: Adding capacitance to SENSOR_5V will cause a surge current when U7P turns on, so I would only capacitance if needed. U7P could be turned on more slowly by adding RC to the gate to reduce the surge current. Even better (but more expensive) use an integrated power switch IC.

Comment: @EE_socal re: integrated power switch IC, can you recommend one, for example?

Answer (score 1):

In case the cable inductance is creating back emfs that lift the 5 volt power supply (via the body diode of the output MOSFET), I'd want to put a 5.6 volt zener diode on the output like this: -

[image]

Adding the capacitors is fine but try this first because it could deliver a reason rather than just a blanket solution.

Comment: The Zener diode achieves nothing since the capacitance on the +5V net would absorb any current, and the body diode limit the excursion to 5.7V anyway.